# WebView and HTML with CSS3 columns (multi-column layout)

Tags: android-layout, css, android-webview

I'm trying to use HTML content in WebView control. This HTML content has CSS3 columns.

My goal is to make WebView scroll only horizontally and make use of columns.
But even if I set fixed height (fill_parent) I am able to scroll vertically.

I've tried to disable scrollbars, use setLoadWithOverviewMode but with no effect.

So, the question is - how to make WebView scroll only horizonally, so it displays HTML content in columns? (I saw similar effect in Windows 8 apps).

Comment: I am not sure, but this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574769/horizontal-scrolling
might be useful..

Comment: Thanks for reply. In my scenario there are many device sizes, so I don't know column height. In my perfect solution I would like content to be automatically split on columns and to fit device height.

Comment: I'm not sure but if you use `box-sizing` it may not be supported by your device. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing