# Multiple divs within a div — horizontal scolling

Tags: jquery, css

I have a question similar to the one asked before here 
[Horizontal Scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574769/horizontal-scrolling) and
[Horizontal scroll in DIV with many small DIV's inside (no text)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431101/horizontal-scroll-in-div-with-many-small-divs-inside-no-text) .

But an additional constraint is that I will be adding `div` programatically and may not know the size of each `div` upfront.
In this case is it possible to achieve horizontal scroll?

How should the HTML/CSS look?

Comment: please provide your code and what you have done so far. By now you have just provided us with info on why your question is not a duplicate of another

Comment: Indeed. How is this one different?

Comment: Well the snip below answered my query. i did not add code primarily for brevity. Thank you all for the time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button in this example will insert a new div with a randomized width, eventually resulting in horizontal scrolling. Points of interest: `white-space: nowrap` and `overflow: scroll` on the container; `display: inline-block` on the child divs.

```js
var container = document.getElementById('items');

function addItem() {
  var d = document.createElement('div');
  d.style.width = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 20 + 'px';
  container.appendChild(d);
}
```

```css
#items {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow:scroll;
}

#items div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addItem()">Add Item</button>

<div id="items"></div>
```